# How to enter username and password in Facebook using class names

Tags: selenium, authentication, webdriver, classname

After doing lot of R&D on google and `StackOverflow` i am posting this query..
i want to enter the username and password on Facebook using ONLY class name, I dont want to use type, name, id for this.. i tried with all possible options but no luck can someone provide the solution for this.. 
here is my code..

```
package login;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.testng.annotations.*;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class MercuryLogin1 {

  private WebDriver driver;

  private String baseUrl;

  @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)

  public void setUp() throws Exception {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Automation_Info\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Automation_Info\\Selenium\\geckodriver-v0.9.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");

    driver = new ChromeDriver();

    baseUrl = "http://facebook.com/";   

    //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

  }

  @Test

  public void testMercuryLogin1() throws Exception {

    driver.get(baseUrl + "/");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class=inputtext][0]")).sendKeys("tutorial");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='nputtext][1]")).sendKeys("tutorial");

  }

  @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)

  public void tearDown() throws Exception {

    //driver.quit();

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to enter user name and password using their class, try using below `By.xpath()` :-

```
public void testMercuryLogin1() throws Exception {

    driver.get(baseUrl + "/");

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

    WebElement user = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("(.//input[@class = 'inputtext'])[1]")))

    user.sendKeys("tutorial");

    WebElement pass = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("(.//input[@class = 'inputtext'])[2]")))

    pass.sendKeys("tutorial");

  }
```

**Note** :- I'm not sure why are you going to enter value using `class Name` while it could be simply enter by using `By.id("email")` and `By.id("pass")`. I'm suggesting you from the performance perspective using `By.id` is much faster than other locator. So make it priority first if it is possible.

Hope it helps...:)

Comment: Thanks for the info Saurabh,  but i dont want to use id or name i wanted to use only CLASS name...

Comment: @SantoshGaddam updated the answer with class. try it..:)

Comment: @SantoshGaddam But I'm suggesting you try using `By.id` here becasue it's much faster than using other locator...:).